# What's the record for highest number of biographies on a single person?

Tags: cinema-history, biopic, most-appearances

I recently realized that so far there have been 4 movies about Steve Jobs' life, however ridiculous that might be, it made me wonder if there was another person that has enjoyed the same amount of interest or greater, I think for the sake of brevity we should exclude figures that weren't around the 20th and 21st century. I'm interested in recent public figures.

So to summarize the question: What's the record for highest number of biographies on a single person?

Comment: I've voted to close this. I get the question, but I think this is too much of a trivia question. Problem is, what about people like *Joan of Arc*? *Henry the Eighth*? *Jesus*? I'm not sure what differentiates the hundreds of biographical films, that have a little artistic license from the modern films on somebody like Steve Jobs, which have a little artistic license. I think this would rapidly turn into a list question.

Comment: @AndrewMartin Doesn't most or all [tag:most-appearances] fall under same kind of problem?

Comment: @AndrewMartin you're absolutely correct, and tbh i'm not interested much in every historical figure. So i'll modify the question to narrow it down.

Comment: @AnkitSharma: Possibly. Either way, I think it's too broad to get a definitive answer. So I post an answer I think is the most. Someone else posts one with more. Someone else posts one with more - and  you end up with a list basically. Which I actually don't mind, I think it's a useful question to be honest - but not sure if it's on-topic or not, that's all.

Comment: I guess there are countless movies about Hitler, you can find many different list with 40+ movies. But then it will become difficult, which movies are biographies, this is difficult to decide in many cases... The efford to join all lists and filter for "real" biographies about him is to high for me, so i dont post this as an answer.

Comment: @AndrewMartin On the other hand we had millions of those questions before and usually deemed them valid. Pretty much everything under `first-appearance` and `most-appearances`. That's at least quite some precedent, what ever you make of that, though. But I tend to agree that the specific definition of what is a biography and what is an important person might be a bit difficult here.

Comment: Is scope limited to Hollywood movies only ? In bollywood I can guess that there are 7  movies about Bhagat Singh and would be many more for Mahatma Gandhi. Wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_artistic_depictions_of_Mahatma_Gandhi

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I took the very unscientific approach of using Wikipedia and their [List of biographical films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biographical_films). I then put all the information into a spreadsheet, removed *a lot* of annoying merged cells and came up with a list and turned this into a hopefully pretty graph:

[image]

Using this, and ignoring non 20th/21st century people, it looks like *[Adolf Hitler](https://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=adolf%20hitler&meta=&safe=active&gws_rd=ssl)* and *[Albert Schweitzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Schweitzer)* lead the way with seven films each.

Of course, Wikipedia's list of biographical films can be edited by *anyone* and is in no way definitive - but I can't find any other list on the Internet tracking it. Interestingly, they had just *three* films for Steve Jobs (as out of the [six films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Jobs_(film)) created about him, they considered three *biographical* and three *documentaries*.

Comment: 12 films for Jesus is way less then I would have expected

Comment: yes - maybe it's because he was looking only under _biographical_ films. Including other categories in where Jesus would be better categorized, like _religious_ films, or maybe _fiction_ would have resulted in a lot more films for sure.

Comment: Where does "*Abraham Lincoln, Vampire Hunter*" fit?  Or for that matter "*Jesus Christ, Vampire Hunter*"?  That also is a thing that exists for some reason.

Comment: The biggest shocker on this list for me is Albert Schweitzer - he's the only one I'd never heard of.  I find it highly suspect that he's tied for first place with Hitler, but I guess it all comes down to how strictly you define "biography".  (Also, most of his movies are in French or German, so maybe he's just not that well known in the English-speaking world...)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Like you, I had never heard of him either, so it was definitely a surprise to me.

Comment: I'm surprised that Wyatt Earp isn't in this list. I thought there was some bit of trivia about him having the most appearances in film (real character). I guess a lot of those films don't count as true biographies.

Answer (score 20):

There are literally dozens of movies about Wong Fei-hung, who died in 1924 and therefore qualifies for your time range. Granted, most of those movies aren't well-known outside China / Hong Kong.

And you might want to make a *very* close inspection before declaring that e.g. Iron Monkey (1993) is a "biographical" account of his childhood! So not all of them qualify as biographies. I think you'd be able to find almost a continuum from "sincere attempt to recount events that actually occurred" to "complete fiction that just uses his name", and draw the line where you want within that.

Comment: *And you might want to make a very close inspection before declaring that e.g. Iron Monkey (1993) is "biographical"!* - I'm not sure who you're referring to. Who has made the claim? Agree about the difficulty of understanding what's biography, what isn't and who qualifies, but Wong Fei-hung looks a decent bet.

Comment: @AndrewMartin: I'm not saying anyone made the claim, I just mean that the raw number of movies in which Wong Fei-hung is a major character, doesn't translate to a number of "biographies". And unfortunately I'm not equipped even to estimate how many of them can reasonably be called biographical, we need a Hong Kong cinema buff.

Comment: Ah got it, understood. That makes sense. Well, +1 from me: this certainly seems to be fit with OP's ask.

Comment: I feel like he has become more of a legend. Most movies about him might be as biographical as *Young Guns* is to Billy the Kid. Meaning I suspect there's a lot of embellishment, to say the least.

Comment: @ToddWilcox: true, but I'm not absolutely certain the same can't be said for those Steve Jobs biographies in the question. Unless there's some "official" definition of biography that could be used for the purposes of defining this record, it's going to be a matter of opinion which movies to include, based on how much embellishment to allow. How much of Aaron Sorkin's dialogue was actually ever spoken by Steve Jobs? Maybe a few public speeches where Sorkin used excerpts from the transcripts? But we probably still call it biographical as long as it fictionalizes "enough" real events.

Comment: Also, "less than half of movies about Wong Fei-hung", most of them having been discounted, could still be a *lot* more movies than those Andrew found about Hitler or Schweizer, which is why I thought him worth considering. A "biographical movie" gets a lot more license before we call shenanigans, than a written "biography" does, so the question is just how much.

Comment: I wanted to know this guy so I searched his name, and IMDB lists 100.0 movies containing a Character named Wong Fei Hung http://www.imdb.com/character/ch0000742/is listed in the casting.

Comment: US releases weren't a precondition stated in the question, nor does the OP's profile say "United States" on it. Bias detected...

Comment: I'm not saying they shouldn't be counted on that ground. I'm pre-emptively explaining why some people might never have heard of this movie staple, just on the off-chance that anyone reading isn't familiar with the huge amount of work around Wong Fei-hung ;-)

Comment: I'll change the statement, though. I think if this site as largely populated with Americans even though I'm not American myself.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'd almost guarantee the "winner" of most biographies will be someone whose films are made outside of the western world.